# Why is getBackgroundPage() not defined in chrome.runtime for me?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to access `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage()` from my content script but I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage is not a function(anonymous function) @ VM11844:1InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM11665:883InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM11665:816InjectedScript.evaluateOnCallFrame @ VM11665:942window.onload @ run.js:101

Here's what my manifest.json looks like:

```
{
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["run.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start"
  }],
  "description": "Hello world!",
  "homepage_url": "https://tryprospect.com",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/16x16.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Hello world",
  "permissions": ["storage", "management"],
  "version": "v0.1",
  "web_accessible_resources": ["html/*"]
}
```

Am I missing something? Perhaps a permission?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the bit when you're calling the function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most chrome.* APIs are not available to content scripts. They can only be used from background or event pages, popups, or other extension views you define.

In particular you can't use `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage()` because the window objects for the extension live in a different process than the content script. The only way to communicate between content scripts and the rest of your extension is via messaging or storage.